# Django app runs locally but I get CSRF verification failed on Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku, csrf

My app runs fine at `heroku local` but after deployed to Heroku, every time I try to login/register/login as admin, it returns this error shown below.

I have tried to put `@csrf_exempt` on `profile` views, but that didn't fix the issue.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message is fairly self-explanatory (please excuse typos as I can't copy from an image):

```
Origin checking failed - https://pacific-coast-78888.herokuapp.com does not match any trusted origins
```

The domain you are using is not a trusted origin for CSRF.

There is then a link to the documentation, which I suspect goes to [the Django CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/csrf/), though [the documentation for the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS) might be more useful:

> A list of trusted origins for unsafe requests (e.g. `POST`).
>
> For requests that include the `Origin` header, Django’s CSRF protection requires that header match the origin present in the `Host` header.

Look in your `settings.py` for `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` and add `https://pacific-coast-78888.herokuapp.com` to the list. If that setting doesn't already exist, simply add it:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://pacific-coast-78888.herokuapp.com"]
```

Comment: One thing that bit me in the ass - the value in the list cannot include the trailing slash, which you'd tend to add if you just cut and pasted the url from the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

If **Heroku** uses **django "4.x.x" version**:

Then, if the error is as shown below:

> Origin checking failed -  [https://example.com](https://example.com/)  does not match any trusted origins.

Add this code below to **"settings.py"**:

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://example.com']
```

In your case, you got this error:

> Origin checking failed -  [https://pacific-coast-78888.herokuapp.com](https://praktikum6.jhoncena.repl.co/)  does not match any trusted origins.

So, you need to add this code below to **your "settings.py"**:

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://pacific-coast-78888.herokuapp.com']
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears you do not have your heroku address as a trusted origin in the setting.py file of your project, to do this, you can use corsheaders

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

then in your settings.py file

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
   ...
   'corsheaders',  
   ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  ...
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
```

If you were not yet deployed you could add `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` but because you know where your app is deployed using a whitelist for the origins is a much better idea

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
  'https://pacific-coast-78888.herokuapp.com',
)
```

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with CORS?

Comment: still an error ```?: (corsheaders.E013) Origin 'u' in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST is missing scheme or netloc
 HINT: Add a scheme (e.g. https://) or netloc (e.g. example.com).```